# How to define the PointerToRawData for a new section header?

Tags: c#, portable-executable

I'm trying to add a new section header in the PE but I don't know how to calculate the PointerToRawData for the new section .

As I know , it should be the size of raw data + the PointerToRawData of the last section but the section's SizeOfRawData I'm adding into the PE is equal to 0 and the virtual size to 1000.

Could someone help with some tips?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PointerToRawData is the file location of the data that belongs to this section. If your section does not have any data associated with it, it can be the same as the value for the previous section, or - I think - zero.

Comment: All fields are set to 0 and I'm getting in PE EXPLORER : Warning! Section <.rsrc> (7) extends beyond the raw file offset of section <.news> (8). only virtual address is set and characteristics. Any idea? ( PS: It tells me it's not a valid win32 application)

Comment: Where do you add your new section, before resources?

Comment: I'm adding the section at the end of the other sections . The last section is .rsrc

Comment: From the error, it sounds like there's a mismatch between PointerToRawData + SizeOfRawData of the .rsrc section and the PointerToRawData value of the following section.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that all SizeOfRawData field values must be whole multiples of the file alignment value (unless zero).

Comment: Make sure PointerToRawData has the correct file alignment.

Comment: Thanks , I've double checked PointerToRawData. But now I'm getting Size of Raw Data (610304) > Size of File Image (584744). but in SizeOfImage,SizeOfCode,SizeOfInitialized from the Optional Header I'm adding the value of the virtual size of the new header.

Comment: The very last section doesn't have to be physically aligned. See: https://code.google.com/p/corkami/wiki/PE#SizeOfRawData

Answer (score 0):

please see the《Portable Executable File Format – A Reverse Engineer View》 at links follows：
http://index-of.es/Windows/pe/CBM_1_2_2006_Goppit_PE_Format_Reverse_Engineer_View.pdf

It exactly says “ it is the offset from the file's beginning to the section's data. ” in it at page 18.
Another useful reference is 《Microsoft Portable Executable and Common Object File Format Specification》,you can find it on Google
I am also searching for this information and share this with you~
good lucks~